# Recharge by clicking on tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, google-visualization

I need to reload the contents of the tab by clicking on the link, because I'm trying `rendering` problems on the `Google Chart`.

I made a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b7xexjta/16/) that represents the problem. Notice the rendering difference of the two tabs.

I put a delay, but when I access another tab. Incorrect rendering still happens.

```
setTimeout(function () {
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to wait until the chart's container is visible, before drawing for the first time

see following working snippet...

```js
$(document).foundation();

$('#sac-tabs').on('change.zf.tabs', function() {
  switch ($(this).children('.is-active').text().trim()) {
    case 'Tab 1':
      drawVisualization();
      break;

    case 'Tab 2':
      drawVisualization2();
      break;
  }
});

google.charts.load('current', {
    callback: drawVisualization,
    packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawVisualization() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Departamento', 'Concluídas', 'Andamento', 'Pendentes'],
        ['Vendas', 5, 6, 2],
        ['Peças', 3, 4, 6],
        ['Serviços', 1, 2, 3],
        ['Administrativo', 7, 5, 3]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Gráfico',
        hAxis: {title: 'Departamento'},
        seriesType: 'bars',
        colors: ['#21BA45', '#F90', '#DC3912'],
        series: {5: {type: 'line'}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}

function drawVisualization2() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Departamento', 'Concluídas', 'Andamento', 'Pendentes'],
        ['Vendas', 5, 6, 2],
        ['Peças', 3, 4, 6],
        ['Serviços', 1, 2, 3],
        ['Administrativo', 7, 5, 3]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Gráfico',
        hAxis: {title: 'Departamento'},
        seriesType: 'bars',
        colors: ['#21BA45', '#F90', '#DC3912'],
        series: {5: {type: 'line'}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.1.2/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.1.2/foundation.min.css">
<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-12 columns">
        <ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="sac-tabs">
            <li class="tabs-title is-active">
                <a href="#panel1" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel2">Tab 2</a></li>            
        </ul>
        <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="sac-tabs">
            <div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="panel1">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="medium-12 columns">
                    <p>
                    Expected outcome
                    </p>
                    <div id="chart_div"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel2">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="medium-12 columns">
                    <p>
                    Not a Problem
                    </p>
                       <div id="chart_div2"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem,

Only active tab draw full width, draft.

For solution you want to make one think, when you draw second tab draft, that time active second tab using jQuery after that run "chart. draws" commnad.

I hope you understand. Enjoy :)